# Change timestamp in a date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

First of all - I am a total noob, so I don't even know if I am calling it the right thing.

This, of course, also affects the results I am getting when searching. So far I have not found what I am looking for.

And on top of this, my first language is not English...

But here goes:

I have a booking calendar that is using mySQL. Apparently, there has been a problem with the php date function, and something got patched on the server. This results in no bookings getting displayed.

I narrowed it down to the timestamp in the date that is stored in mySQL:

The old version had 23:00 GMT as time
The new version has 00:00 GMT as time

By manually subtracting 82800 from the number stored as start date and end date in the database, I was able to make bookings appear. But there are A LOT of bookings, and I have been trying to find a solution where I can run an SQL query to update all bookings.

```
I would need to test if the date ends in 23:00 GMT
If true, then subtract 82800
And go to the next post in the table
```

Or at least something in that area. Maybe there even is a standard way of fixing this...

As I am totally new to this, feel free to point me to the correct thing to search for or a link to the solution somewhere else.

I access the database through phpMyAdmin.

Comment: the column with the date is timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your column is in proper datetime format, you can do it in a single query. (Be sure to take a back-up first, though.)

```
UPDATE your_table 
SET booking_time = DATE_SUB(booking_time, INTERVAL 23 HOUR)
WHERE booking_time LIKE '%23:00:00'
```

If it's in, say, varchar, you'll likely want to write PHP, which is going to take a bit longer:

1. Fetch all of the bookings.
2. Loop through them. For each booking:
3. Use standard string functions to check if the booking is 23:00 GMT.
4. If it is, extract the datetime and use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to get it in Unix time format. (If it is not, just continue the loop.)
5. Subtract 82800 from the Unix time value, and use [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to re-format it into the date you want.
6. Update the booking row in the database with the new timestamp.